# Seeding MongoDB nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, odm

Seeking for advice about a nodejs app and mongoDB seeding.

I have a nodejs app which it should be able to seed a mongodb once i export a variable DB_HOST which the correct IP.

I am able to go through all the steps and be able to ping my mongodb instance from my app instance.

When i run the command node seeds/seed.js

i get:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-104-49:~/AppFolder/app$ node seeds/seed.js 
(node:1799) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
Database Cleared
Database Seeded
```

but if i log in my mongodb instance and in mongo console
run `show dbs;`

all i have is:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> show dbs;
local  0.000GB
posts  0.000GB
```

the posts, should have some data in, as my `node seeds/seed.js` should create some random posts and pass them to mongodb posts.

now, i checked my mongodb logs for troubleshooting but i dont have any error, actually it says that he received client data from my app instance:

```
2020-05-13T01:47:32.158+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] New replica set config in use: { _id: "rs0", version: 3, protocolVersion: 1, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "ip-10-0-1-100:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 }, { _id: 1, host: "ip-10-0-2-100:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 }, { _id: 2, host: "ip-10-0-3-100:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 } ], settings: { chainingAllowed: true, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10, electionTimeoutMillis: 10000, getLastErrorModes: {}, getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 }, replicaSetId: ObjectId('5ebb51b31fa00dc07eacc09f') } }
2020-05-13T01:47:32.158+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] This node is ip-10-0-1-100:27017 in the config
2020-05-13T01:47:32.158+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to ip-10-0-3-100:27017
2020-05-13T01:47:32.161+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to ip-10-0-3-100:27017, took 4ms (2 connections now open to ip-10-0-3-100:27017)
2020-05-13T01:47:32.161+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member ip-10-0-2-100:27017 is now in state STARTUP2
2020-05-13T01:47:32.162+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to ip-10-0-3-100:27017, took 4ms (2 connections now open to ip-10-0-3-100:27017)
2020-05-13T01:47:32.163+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member ip-10-0-3-100:27017 is now in state STARTUP
2020-05-13T01:47:33.026+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] transition to primary complete; database writes are now permitted
2020-05-13T01:47:34.162+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member ip-10-0-2-100:27017 is now in state SECONDARY
2020-05-13T01:47:34.164+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member ip-10-0-3-100:27017 is now in state SECONDARY
2020-05-13T01:47:59.204+0000 I NETWORK  [conn54] received client metadata from 10.0.104.49:57540 conn54: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "2.2.34" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-1106-aws" }, platform: "Node.js v8.17.0, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.18" }
2020-05-13T01:48:32.162+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Ending idle connection to host ip-10-0-3-100:27017 because the pool meets constraints; 1 connections to that host remain open
```

but still my posts is empty.

Any idea about why is this happening? i always had a problem with step.

i dont know if this might help but i post the important parts of the app js:

this is posts.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

and this is the seeds.js:

```
var Post = require('../models/post');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var faker = require('faker');

if(process.env.DB_HOST) {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_HOST);

  Post.remove({} , function(){
    console.log('Database Cleared');
  });

  var count = 0;
  var num_records = 100;

  for(var i = 0; i < num_records; i++) {
    Post.create({
      title: faker.random.words(),
      body: faker.lorem.paragraphs()
    }, function(){
      count++;
      if(count >= num_records) {
        mongoose.connection.close();
        console.log("Database Seeded");
      }
```

all what i had to do, is set the DB_HOST to a mongodb link.

which in my case is:

```
export DB_HOST=mongodb://ip-10-0-1-100:27017/posts,ip-10-0-2-100:27017/posts,ip-10-0-3-100:27017/posts?replicaSet=rs0
```

there are 3 because i am working with a replicaSet. i have the IPs set in etc/hosts and i am able to ping all of them from my app instance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which log statements get printed? 'Database Cleared' ? "Database Seeded"?

Comment: i get both of them. First 'Database Cleared' and right after 'Database Seeded', after i run my npm install and npm start. But if i log in my mongodb instance and in the mongo shell i run `show dbs;` i can see that the posts collection has been created but with 0.000GB.. afer that if i go to my browser adn put myappip:27017/posts i get the error "unable to connect"

Comment: So i figure out what its wrong. My app instance by default should be listening on port 3000, but i used a reverse proxy to port 80. Now once my seed triggers and i try to go on `myappinstanceip:27017/posts` i got the error unable to connect. BUT if i go on`myappinstanceip:3000/posts` i am able to display my page. Now i need to figure out how to reverse this proxy so that by default should listen on port 80